# Python local variables as reference?

Tags: python, class, variables

I'm trying to get my little script working but i don't what the problem is, one of the methods will modify my test var even if i don't return it, i mean, i want to work with that locally and NOT to return the value. This is not my actual code but you can be sure that represent it.

UPDATED: i'm using a dict

```
    >>> class check:
    ...   def pathgen(self,test):
    ...     test['a']=0
    ...     print test
    ...   def assign(self):
    ...     test={'a':1}
    ...     self.pathgen(test)
    ...     print test #WILL PRINT 0
    ... 
    >>> a=check()
    >>> a.assign()
    {'a': 0}
    {'a': 0}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are working with function-local names. Set attributes on the instance (via `self`) to share information between methods:

```
class check:
     def pathgen(self):
         self.test = 0
         print self.test
     def assign(self):
         self.test = 1
         self.pathgen()
         print self.test
```

Comment: Maybe my python is bad? using your code
        >>> a=check()
        >>> a.assign()
        0
0

Comment: Thanks i understand this a bit better. Can you check my updated question with dict?

Comment: @user1208656: You are changing a mutable object, changing the *contents* of `test`, not what the variable points to.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, 'pathgen' will modify whatever its first parameter is pointing at.
To avoid that you could make a copy of 'test' before making any changes to it

More info on copy here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

```
class check:
    def pathgen(self,test):
        local_copy = test.copy()
        local_copy['a'] = 0
        print local_copy
```

Comment: @user1208656 here is your answer

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is wrong. The `WILL PRINT 0` line will, in fact, print `1`.

Note that the situation would be different if `test` were a list, and `pathgen` were to modify it (e.g. by appending an element):

```
class check:
     def pathgen(self,test):
         test.append(1)
         print test
     def assign(self):
         test=[]
         self.pathgen(test)
         print test

check().assign()
```

This would, in fact, print `[1]` twice.

This can be addressed by making a copy of `test` in `pathgen`:

```
class check:
     def pathgen(self,test):
         test=test[:]    # make a shallow copy of `test'
         test.append(1)
         print test
     def assign(self):
         test=[]
         self.pathgen(test)
         print test

check().assign()
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please check again my updated question with dict?